# how can I provide Future<String> to stream that expects String in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my `flutter` app I'm building a scrollable list filled with data from FireBase. So far my code looks as follows:

```
class FollowersListState extends State<FollowersUsersList> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('user').where("author", isEqualTo: getUserEmail()).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return CupertinoActivityIndicator();

        return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.docs);
      },
    );
  }
```

In the code above there is this line:

```
where("author", isEqualTo: getUserEmail())
```

`getUserEmail()` is a method that takes the user's email from local shared preferences:

```
Future<String> getUserEmail() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getString('loginEmail');
}
```

but - as you can see - it returns the `Future<String>` instead of `String`, so I cannot use it in my implementation in the `StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>`. What is the best way to handle it in that case?

Thanks!

Comment: can't you put `getUserEmail` in `initState`?

Comment: @pskink I was not sure how exactly I could use `FutureBuilder` to build a stream, could you please give me some hint or show some quick example code as the answer to this question? thanks!

Comment: @JohnJoe can you please show me some short code snippet how could I do it? I still cannot assign the returned value to a normal string there... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unpack a `Future` into a synchronous value within the build method. You will need to wrap the `StreamBuilder` in a `FutureBuilder` that gets the email ahead of time:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: getUserEmail(),
  builder: (_, emailSnapshot) {
    if (!emailSnapshot.hasData) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator(); // Or something
    }
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('user').where("author", isEqualTo: emailSnapshot.data).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return CupertinoActivityIndicator();

        return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.docs);
      },
    ),
  },
),
```

Comment: thank you, it works!